# How to temporarily set the featured image for a post when the post is loaded

Tags: php

I like to set my hero sections of my site to dynamically use the featured image as the background. This works great for most things but sometimes not, such as when it's an archive page and it just grabs the featured image for the first post. I know how to do what I'm trying to do with shortcode but I'm trying to make it work with Elementor Pro's dynamic tags which really only have so many options. I don't want to actually set anything in the database. I'd really like to be able to just change what featured image gets pulled for that view.

Something like this:

```
add_action('init', 'switch_featured_image');
function switch_featured_image(){
    $default_image_attachment_id = 999;
    if (is_archive()) {
        /*
         set queried object featured image to $default_image_attachment_id
         then whenever anything tries to get the current featured image
         they'll use $default_image_attachment_id
        */            
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you setting your the hero section image as the featured image in your theme files, or through Elementor? If you're doing it through code, you could something similar to the code you've written here by using the `is_archive()` if statement

Comment: If it's through Elementor, the question will have to be closed as questions about third-party plugins are off-topic.

Comment: I'm assigning the hero image through Elementor but this is not an Elementor question. The question is how to programmatically change the data that WordPress is pulling which is the same as the data that Elementor is pulling. If I can change that with code, the Elementor issue will take care of itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `post_thumbnail_html` action hook will be the one you're looking for. This allows you to add conditional logic to change the source url depending on the page you're looking at.

```php
function new_post_thumbnail_html( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {
    $new_html = $html;
    if ( is_archive() ) :
         $new_html = '<img src="https://your-image-source.com" alt="Your image alt tag">';
    endif;
    return $new_html;
}
add_action( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'new_post_thumbnail_html', 10, 5 );
```

Depending on how Elementor treats the featured image for your hero section, it may do a `has_post_thumbnail()` check before displaying the featured image. In that case, this solution will not work, and you might try [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/252785/224682) solution instead.